# How can i reimport a realm in keycloak. If it already exists

Tags: keycloak

Not able to import realm json using Keycloak import on keycloak version 15.0.2. I am running keycloak in a docker container.

Below is the docker volume in compose

volumes:

```
- ./keycloak-realm.json:/tmp/keycloak-realm.json
```

**Environment variables for keycloak**

```
KEYCLOAK_IMPORT=/tmp/keycloak-realm.json -Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled -Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=OVERWRITE_EXISTING
```

The import fails with already exists error. When using migration strategy also getting the same error.

How can i import realm even if it exists?

Error from Keycloak:

> 04:47:48,047 INFO  [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread
> Pool -- 70) KC-SERVICES0003: Not importing realm sso from file
> /tmp/keycloak-realm.json.  It already exists.
> 04:47:48,068 INFO  [org.keycloak.services] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) KC-SERVICES0003: Not importing realm sso from file
> /tmp/keycloak-realm.json.  It already exists.

Comment: Hey, looking for the same but for the new version: 18.0.0. Pleas share if you found how to fix it

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the official docker image, you will need to set the strategy via JAVA_OPTS_APPEND environment variable. In your case:

```
KEYCLOAK_IMPORT=/tmp/keycloak-realm.json
JAVA_OPTS_APPEND=-Dkeycloak.profile.feature.upload_scripts=enabled -Dkeycloak.migration.strategy=OVERWRITE_EXISTING
```

Comment: Hey, any idea how to do it in the new 18.0.0 version? Those variables seems to be removed from it

Comment: @Kostanos Does this help? https://www.keycloak.org/server/importExport

Comment: Oh man, this works, but, it deletes existing users... This is awful. My goal is to able to propagate the configuration from one environment to another, but the current import can't properly handle it as it deletes the original realm with all users in it...